# GORM auto flush when request ends without calling save

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have prepared simple controller action to test behaviour related with unexpected commiting changes to datatbase:

```
def testSimple() {
    Product p = Product.findById(1);

    p.name = "test doneee"

    //p.save flush:true

    respond p
}
```

The changes are persisted in database even the `save()` has not been called. How to avoid saving entity without calling `save()`?

Comment: Just don't modify it, and it won't be saved. Why do you modify an entity if you don't want it to be modified?

Comment: Imagine that after modification of object (like POJO) you execute some logic that implict the `save` should not occur. Please do not gainsay such trivial problem.

Comment: Then rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grails registers an OpenSessionInView interceptor which starts a Hibernate Session and the beginning of each request, and flushes and closes it at the end of the request. This is primarily done to allow lazy-loaded one-to-many instances and many-to-one collections to load on demand. One side effect is what you're seeing, that changing a persistent instance causes the changes to get pushed to the database even without a `save()` call. This is because changing it marks it dirty, and Hibernate discovers all dirty objects during the flush and pushes the changes to the database.

To avoid changes like this from being persisted, use the http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html method to detach it from the Session.

p.s. Unrelated, but you should use `get` instead of `findById`, since `get` does the same thing but has much better caching behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This can make your order of operations a nightmare. 
[See this SO post][1]
[Grails GORM auto update issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546269/grails-gorm-auto-update-issue?rq=1)

It makes using the getPersistentValue() method on an object scary in a large application context. If there is a database call somewhere in the chain, even if it is totally unrelated,  your persisted values will change.

I did find that marking database calls as readonly prevents trigger of auto save.
For example in a a service

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

  class TestService{

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   def queryDatabase(){
      //this operation won't trigger auto updates now, yay
   }

  }
```

But not all cases would be read only, and again in a large context your code could go ka-put if another developer doesn't explicitly set readonly. But that's grails for you, **complexity through convention**